# Can a delegate declaration inherit from another delegate declaration?

Tags: .net, generics, .net-4.0, delegates

Is there a way I can write the following without typing out the whole signature again?

```
//desired base signature
    public delegate string BaseDelegate<TProfile, TResult>(string requestorID, DateTime sentDate, string serviceID,
        string source, TProfile profile, out DateTime recieved, out DateTime sent, out string psatSystemID, out TResult[] result);

//ugly version of child
public delegate string CurriedDelegate<T>(string requestorId, DateTime sentDate, string serviceId, string source,
T profile, out DateTime recieved, out DateTime sent, out string psatSystemID, out T[] result);

//syntax sugar,doesn't compile
    public BaseDelegate<T,T> CurriedDelegate<T>; //TProfile is same type as TResult
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no way of doing that, although you could create a `CurriedDelegate<T>` from a `BaseDelegate<TProfile, TResult>` if the two type parameters were the same.

It seems to me like a better solution would be to encapsulate the various parameters in a separate type anyway. That really is a horribly long signature to start with, and presumably the parameters *are* related to each other.

(I'd also try to avoid using so many `out` parameters - perhaps you've actually got *two* types to encapsulate here, one for input and one for output?)

Comment: yeah the code i'm calling is out-of-scope for cleanup at this phase in the project. from what I can tell in most cases 2 parameters out of the lot are even used at all in 98% of the service layer. When you say I could create a `CurriedDelegate<T>`, you mean instantiate, not define a short/sweet type signature, right? In >80% of the service layer code `TProfile` and `TResult` are the same.

Comment: @Maslow: Yes, if you already had a `BaseDelegate<T1, T2>` you could use `new CurriedDelegate<Whatever>(existingDelegate)`.